# Airflow 2.0 support for DataprocClusterCreateOperator

Tags: airflow, google-cloud-composer, airflow-2.x

In our project we are using DataprocClusterCreateOperator which was under contrib `from airflow.contrib.operators import dataproc_operator`. It is working fine with airflow version `1.10.14`.

We are in a process of upgrading to Airflow 2.1.2 wherein while testing or dags which requires spinning of DataProc Cluster we found error as `airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: Invalid arguments were passed to DataprocClusterCreateOperator (task_id: <task_id>). Invalid arguments were: **kwargs: {'config_bucket': None, 'autoscale_policy': None}`

I am not able to see any links for this operator support in Airflow 2 so that I can identify the new params or the changes which happened.
Please share the relevant link.

We are using `google-cloud-composer version 1.17.2`  having Airflow version `2.1.2`.

Comment: The supported parameters for the `DataprocClusterCreateOperator` in `Airflow 2.x` can be found [here](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/main/airflow/providers/google/cloud/operators/dataproc.py#L447) in the source code. The cluster configuration parameters that are passed to the `DataprocClusterCreateOperator` are given [here](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/main/airflow/providers/google/cloud/operators/dataproc.py#L90).

Comment: Also, as mentioned in the below answer, an example implementation of the operator can be found [here](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/stable/operators/cloud/dataproc.html#create-a-cluster).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Airflow 2.0, 3rd party provider (like Google in this case) operators/hooks has been moved away from Airflow core to separate providers packages. You can read more [here](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers/).

Since you are using Cloud Composer, the Google providers package is already installed.

Regarding the `DataprocClusterCreateOperator`, it has been renamed to `DataprocCreateClusterOperator` and moved to `airflow.providers.google.cloud.operators.dataproc` so you can import it with:

```
from airflow.providers.google.cloud.operators.dataproc import DataprocCreateClusterOperator
```

The accepted parameters differ from the one included in Airflow 1.x. You can find an example of usage [here](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/stable/operators/cloud/dataproc.html#create-a-cluster).

Answer (score 1):

The supported parameters for the `DataprocCreateClusterOperator` in **Airflow 2** can be found [here](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/main/airflow/providers/google/cloud/operators/dataproc.py#L447), in the source code. The cluster configuration parameters that can be passed to the operator can be found [here](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/main/airflow/providers/google/cloud/operators/dataproc.py#L90).

The `DataprocClusterCreateOperator` has been renamed as `DataprocCreateClusterOperator` since January 13, 2020 as per this [Github commit](https://github.com/apache/airflow/commit/f4d3e5e54507f52a00a9b95aa48eb0260e17224d#diff-5435bfccc2d2a6ea12278d978b1be8a19eb076fbda732d39053d6ee7bdc8d545L128) and has been ported from `airflow.contrib.operators` to `airflow.providers.google.cloud.operators.dataproc` import path.

As given in @itroulli's answer, an example implementation of the operator can be found [here](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/stable/operators/cloud/dataproc.html#create-a-cluster).